# Symfony UniqueEntity relation not throwing Assert, throwing Duplicate Key Error

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I have my UserProfile entity in API Platform and I am determining the owner by JWT login token. When I create a user profile when a user already has one, I'd like to throw an error saying as such. However, when I do I get a database error message about having a duplicate entity.

Every thread on Stack Overflow with this question mentions making sure there is a UniqueEntity for each field (in my case, username & owner), which I have done.

```
#[UniqueEntity('username')]
#[UniqueEntity('owner')]
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UserProfile
{
    /**
```

Unfortunately, I am still getting the same message:

> "debugMessage": "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user_profile (id, username, first_name, last_name, birthday, biography, website, owner_id, image_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["0a90b58d-12ba-4f00-a924-5c5b6073389a", "test", null, null, null, null, null, "501a54a4-5ec3-4fd7-9821-6421605e733f", 2]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  ***duplicate key value violates unique constraint*** "uniq_d95ab4057e3c61f9"\nDETAIL:  Key (owner_id)=(501a54a4-5ec3-4fd7-9821-6421605e733f) already exists.",

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="userProfile", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    #[Groups(["userProfile:read"])]
    #[Assert\Valid()]
    private $owner;
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you need to use [UniqueEntity constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) to validate your user before flushing. Otherwise you'll get a mysql error trying to insert it.

Try using something like this :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"firstField", "secondField", "..."})
 */
```

Comment: Hi, I have the UniqueEntity constraint in my code above here. Are you recommending a different usage of it?

Comment: Hi, firstly do you validate your entity before flushing ?

Comment: Flushing is handled on the API Platform Framework side, and the UniqueEntity validation on username here works, so yes, it is being validated before flushing. The `owner` relation does not seem to get checked.

Comment: As described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#fields) several fields must be in an array with one UniqueEntity if you want that the combination of username and owner to be unique. If you want these fields to be individually unique then use two UniqueEntity. Could you show your entire UserProfile class ?

Comment: I do want them to be individually unique, and I already am using two UniqueEntity attributes.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/brettins/5bd8e08f90109d1145f6a46f97fefea6

Comment: Maybe with this syntax : 
    @UniqueEntity(fields={"firstField"})
    @UniqueEntity(fields={"secondField"})
Sorry I couldn't help you more :/